# React JS : Chakra UI - Split view

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am looking for a split view in react js , i am using chakra ui for my layouts and i am not able to achive it .

Left Pane is Menu which has a fixed height (no scrolling needed)
Right Pane is the page which gets loaded every-time user selects an option in left menu.
Right pane should be scrollable.

Answer (score -2):

You should give a try on the Choc-UI Layouts for achieving this:

https://choc-ui.com/docs/application-shells/sidebar-layouts

Or here too:

https://chakra-templates.dev/navigation/sidebar

On the links you will get previews of components that have a side bar on left side getting th full height of the viewport, also a sidebar and a container for your app content or other components.

This section is independent of the sidebar and navbar showed on the previews. You can access the code with the show code option on each previo (top-right location)

Try removing the navbar and modifying the width of sidebar, and you will get a split version of the layouts as you are reaching for.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Ok, i will edit my answer for getting a better response on the problem. Thanks for your comment Ethan